Not able to rename column in pandas dataframe
To begin with, here is a pandas dataframe containing data from a Youtube channel for month of April 2024.
  Published_date  Views(in millions)  Likes  Comments  Month
0     2024-04-11                0.10   8239       261    Apr
1     2024-04-05                1.11  67266      1479    Apr
2     2024-04-03                0.26  15059       316    Apr

I wanted to extract month data (number of videos uploaded in April 2024) from the above dataframe. So I used following methods.
videos_per_month = video_data.groupby('Month', as_index=False).size()
videos_per_month

I got the following output.
  Month  No. of videos
0   Apr              3

Next, I wanted to extract the average views per month for April 2024 from the first dataframe. I used following methods.
avg_views_per_month = video_data.groupby('Month', as_index=False).agg(
    {'Views(in millions)': ['mean']})
avg_views_per_month

I got output
  Month  Views(in millions)
         mean
0   Apr                0.49

Next i merged the above two dataframes I extracted using foll. methods
videos_per_month.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
avg_views_per_month.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

avg_views_per_video_by_month = pd.merge(
    videos_per_month,
    avg_views_per_month,
    on='Month')
avg_views_per_video_by_month

I got the following output. I don't know why 'Views in millions' got concatenated with mean.
  Month  No. of videos  (Views(in millions), mean)
0   Apr              3                        0.49

Finally, I tried renaming the (Views(in millions), mean) column using foll. function.
avg_views_per_video_by_month.rename(
    columns={'(Views(in millions), mean)': 'Views'},
    inplace=True)

avg_views_per_video_by_month

But I think the method didn't work and returned the exact same dataframe as above:
  Month  No. of videos  (Views(in millions), mean)
0   Apr              3                        0.49

Why isn't the column being renamed? What am I doing wrong?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Post them as text instead. Information unnecessarily posted as image is considered missing debugging details.

I have edited my post. Is it fine now?

Beside the point, but I can't reproduce this behaviour in Pandas 2 (2.0.3, 2.2.1 and dev). I get MergeError: Not allowed to merge between different levels. (1 levels on the left, 2 on the right). What version are you using?

Look at avg_views_per_video_by_month.columns. It looks like the one you're asking about isn't a string, it's a tuple.

Does this effectively answer your question? Renaming tuple column name in dataframe

Yes. Thanks. I am using v1.5.3.
